# Using "&" in base-x and xquery update

Tags: xml, special-characters, xquery, basex

I am trying to update the text value of a node using xquery. What I have works just fine for numbers and simple text, but I am having issues with special characters.

Usually, when handling xml, I just replace `&` with `&amp;` and things work fine. In the case of my updating expression though, I get a "Expecting quote." error.

These works:

```
replace value of node $v with "testers"
replace value of node $v with "tester's"
replace value of node $v with "tester A and tester B"
```

These fail:

```
replace value of node $v with "tester A & tester B"
replace value of node $v with "tester A &amp; tester B"
```

Ideally, I would also be replacing `"` with `&quot;` but I can't do this until I am able to pass the `&` (or some substitute) via xquery.

Comment: Your first failing query is expected to fail. The second one should work fine -- are you sure you're not having some mismatched quotes somewhere? For example, try `copy $c := <foo>bar</foo>
modify (replace value of node $c with "tester A &amp; tester B")
return $c`.

Comment: ...providing a fully self-contained reproducer (ie. one that sets the context item if appropriate, establishes $v, etc) in the second (expected-to-succeed) case would be helpful. Otherwise, this is arguably CNR.

Answer (score 2):

This does in fact work correctly, as tested with the following document against BaseX 8.2:

```
declare context item := document { <root><txt>old</txt></root> };

copy $c := /root/txt
modify replace value of node $c with "foo &amp; bar"
return $c
```

...which correctly yields:

```
<txt>foo &amp; bar</txt>
```